# Is there any way to access the locations for a vector layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I created a vector layer called "locationGeoJSON" in OpenLayers using a GeoJSON file and I'm trying to use the `.getSource()` method to access the location data for the layer. I'm currently using a workaround where I access the location data with `locationGeoJSON.getSource().Uu`. But I feel like there's some get method that can be used to retrieve the data in a more appropriate manner. I've tried using `locationGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatures()`, but I just get an empty array in return. Can anyone give some insight into this issue? [Here is the console output after I use .getSource() on my vector layer. How do I access the "Uu" property?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMxw6.png)

Answer (score 0):

`locationGeoJSON.getSource().getFeatures()` is correct, but you may have to wait for the geojson file to load before calling it.

```js
locationGeoJSON.getSource().on('featuresloadend', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.getFeatures());
});
```

The object in the console output already has the features because it is linked to the original object and refreshes whenever its state changes.